# Prove that the equation $2^a - 2^b - 1=3^c$ has no integral solution with $a,b\geq 3$

Tags: nt.number-theory

I was looking for a natural power of 3 that could be written like

> Binary format:
>
> 11..(N times)..11011..(M times)..11
>
> Example: 1111110111111111111111 (...isn't a power of 3)

Or could also be written like

> 3^x = 2^a - 2^b - 1
>
> (x is arbitrary, "a" and "b" are natural numbers, a = N-M-1, b = M, and the single zero in binary format is a must)

But couldn't find any, so I thought there might be some proof that there's no such numbers (altho that would contradict intuition) or maybe it can be proven that there might be such numbers?

Comment: $3^1=2^3-2^2-1$

Comment: A bit less trivially, $3^3=2^5-2^2-1$.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to clarify that the single zero in binary format is a must

Comment: Oh, 3^3 = 2^5 - 2^2 - 1 perfectly matches, I got my question answered, thank you very much

Comment: Is it suppose to be $a,b>2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $2^a-2^b-1=3^c$ has no integral solution with $a,b\geq 3$. Indeed, in this case the left-hand side is $\equiv 7\pmod{8}$, while the right-hand side is either $\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ or $\equiv 3\pmod{8}$.

Comment: $b=1$ is clearly impossible, so we are left with $b=2$, $2^a-5=3^c$, which has (at least) the two solutions $8-5=3$ and $32-5=27$ (as noted by Andreas). Are there any more?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Those are the only two solutions, by Bennett's theorem: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/B-CJM-Pillai.pdf